# How to get the group in which the user is authenticated?

Tags: apache2, require

I know that we can manually parse the htaccess group file with REMOTE_USER to get the group name. But is there a way for CGI to get the group name from the apache2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache does not make the full list of groups for the user, or the groups that caused authorization to succeed, available to CGI or other modules.

Comment: Yes. Couldnt find any. Parsing the htaccess file manually to achieve this.